# Shared pointer between two classes as class member

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I have the following class structure:

```
class Bar {
private:
    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>> y_;
public:
    Bar(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>> p):
        y_(p)
    {}

    int getFirstVal() {return y_->at(0);};
};

class Initialiser {
private:
    std::vector<int> x_;
    Bar bar_;
public:
    Initialiser(std::vector<int>& v):
        x_(v),
        bar_(std::make_shared<std::vector<int>>(x_))
    {}

    void set_x(std::vector<int> x) {x_ = x;}

    void check(std::vector<int> x){
        set_x(x);
        std::cout << "New value of x= " << bar_.getFirstVal() << std::endl;
    }
};



int main(){

    std::vector<int> z = {1,2,3};
    Initialiser init(z);

    std::vector<int> x_new = {4,5,6};
    init.check(x_new); // should print 4



}
```

In class Initialiser, I have as private members a vector of ints and an instance of the class Bar. Bar should be initialized with a shared pointer to the vector of ints and this vector should be shared across Initialiser and Bar. Currently however, if Initialiser calls a setter of x, this does not affect the vector inside bar. I demonstrate this in *check()*. Why doesn't *check()* print the value 4 but still the value 1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Initialiser(std::vector<int>& v):
    x_(v),
    bar_(std::make_shared<std::vector<int>>(x_))
{}
```

You create a shared_ptr, that points to a new vector, that is a **copy** of x_. Naturally, modifying one will not affect the other.

The straight-forward solution is to have both Initialiser and Bar hold a shared_ptr to the vector:

```
class Initialiser {
private:
    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>>  x_;
    Bar bar_;
public:
    Initialiser(std::vector<int>& v):
        x_(std::make_shared<std::vector<int>>(v)),
        bar_(x_)
    {}
};
```

---

But since the Bar object is part of the Initialiser object, there really is no need for a smart pointer at all. Bar can simply hold a reference to the vector. There is no lifetime management problem here, because bar_ will never outlive its container nor will the container outlive bar_.

```
class Bar {
private:
    std::vector<int>& y_;
public:
    Bar(std::vector<int>& p):
        y_(p)
    {}

    int getFirstVal() {return y_.at(0);};
};

class Initialiser {
private:
    std::vector<int>  x_;
    Bar bar_;
public:
    Initialiser(std::vector<int>& v):
        x_(v),
        bar_(x_)
    {}
};
```

Note however, that the order of x_ and bar_ matters, thus leaving this a bit brittle. The construction order of member variables is the order of their appearance in the class definition, and not their order in the member initialization list. If the the order was reversed, the behavior of the program would be undefined, since bar_ would be constructed before x_.

This correct ordering also ensures the x_ will not outlive bar_ during object destruction, since members are destroyed in reverse order to their initialization.

Comment: Also worth pointing out that in the case in hand there's no need for `shared_ptr` and it may be appropriate for the `Bar` object to hold either a pointer or a reference to a vector owned by `Initialiser`.

Comment: @DanAllen - Yes, I was just in the process of adding that. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for your help! This is a nice solution.

Comment: Final request! This works because the vector `x_` is declared in the class `Initialiser` before `bar_` and the class will be 'torn down' in reverse of that order by the destructor.